# Remove visual studio code installed with .deb file

Tags: ubuntu-mate, deb

I am trying to remove visual studio code that is in
code_1.72.2-1665614327_amd64.deb.

I used this to install.

```
gdebi code_1.72.2-1665614327_amd64.deb
```

I have tried this.

```
andy@7 ~> sudo dpkg -r code_1.72.2-1665614327_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in
```

According to this, there should be a /usr/share/code/ directory, but it does not exist.

Does that mean that the .deb was not installed?

[image]

Comment: What was the exact command you used to install it? Was it packaged with something else?

Comment: how do you run vscode? dpkg is telling you the issue: the package's *name* is not the same as the name of the *deb file*. Use the name of the package itself in `dpkg -r`.

Comment: You can find the package name with `dpkg -info <filename.deb>`, look at what it says after "Package:"